# How do I draw an outline on a specific wedge of a flex pie chart?

Tags: apache-flex, charts, styling

I want to have a different coloured stroke (outline) used on the pie wedge under the mouse from the outline used on the other wedges.

The PieSeriesItem referenced by the mouseover event doesn't have a stroke parameter, and it looks like it is an all or nothing deal with the outline colour on the whole pie.

Is there any way of specifying the stroke parameter on a specific wedge?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is done by specifying an itemRenderer on the PieSeries. The default is the WedgeItemRenderer, so subclassing will allow overriding the line definition.